# What is the probability that $2-6$ people answered 'no?

Tags: probability

Suppose that in a city of $100$ people, a survey conclude that $30$ of them do not agree (says 'no') with the building of a new luxury apartment. If you randomly chose $12$ people in the city what is the probability that $2$ to $6$ of them are those who disagree with the building of the new luxury apartment?

This seemed to be a binomial probability question.... though I fail to recall how to do so.

bonus point if you know how to solve this in minitab!

Comment: Well perhaps you could try to recall how to do so using a book or something, this seems to be lazy.

Answer (score 1):

The total number of ways to choose $12$ out of $100$ people is:

$$\binom{100}{12}$$

The number of ways to choose them with $2$ to $6$ disagreeing is:

$$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{6}\binom{30}{n}\cdot\binom{100-30}{12-n}$$

So the probability of choosing them with $2$ to $6$ disagreeing is:

$$\frac{\sum\limits_{n=2}^{6}\binom{30}{n}\cdot\binom{100-30}{12-n}}{\binom{100}{12}}\approx89.86\%$$

Answer (score 1):

$n = 100, p = 0.3, q = 1-p = 1-0.3 = 0.7$. We find: $P(2 \leq x \leq 6)$, and this equals to:

$P(2)+P(3)+P(4)+P(5)+P(6) = \displaystyle \sum_{k=2}^6 \binom{100}{k} 0.3^k\cdot 0.7^{100-k}$